# When executing a post request for authentication, an error is issued 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, cross-domain

When executing a `POST` request for authentication, an error is issued. The error occurs when I started to use the CORS request, indicating the static IP that I purchased from the provider.

If I do not use this IP (but specify the localhost), then the request is correctly executed. Spring Boot application.

**Request:**

```
POST http://81.211.111.41:1414/auth/login (IP and port are for example)

body 

  {
  "username":"jeffryus",
  "password":"1234567890"
  }
```

**Controller:**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/auth/")
public class UserAuthenticationController {
    
    @Autowired
    private  JwtUserService jwtUserService;
      
    @Autowired 
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
      
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = { "login" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> authUser(@RequestBody  AuthenticationRequestDto auth) {
        return jwtUserService.login(auth);
    }
      
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = { "signup" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody SignupRequest user) {
        return  jwtUserService.register(user);
    }
```

**Config:**

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private static final String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/auth/**";
    
    @Autowired
    private  JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
     
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
     
    @Autowired
    private JwtUserService jwtUserService;
     
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
     
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http 
            .cors()
                .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()    
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://81.211.111.41:1414"));
        //or any domain that you want to restrict to 
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT"));
        //Add the method support as you like
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(jwtUserService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

**Properties:**

```
server.port=1414

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:*******
spring.datasource.username=*******
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

jwt.token.secret=abc
jwt.token.expired=3600000
```

Error in Postman when sending request:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

an error like this if I broke the syntax in the request.

Comment: @dur If you mean this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path, then when creating, I did not take it into account manually anywhere.

Comment: @dur Internet Assigned Numbers Authority, SamaraLan . And it somehow affects it?And I sort of managed to launch a request through the cors for the specified IP., Only when I removed all the settings in the property file (server.port). But it doesn't have to work like that. Why does not it work with server.port

Comment: @dur no, using everything on the local machine, pointed to the cors request with his static ip address and port, all

Comment: Are you deploying your application in a servlet container or are you running the uber-jar of Spring Boot?